# Closed question about looking to play the unique cars only available in the different demo versions of a game — Can it be reopened?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing, specific-question, reopen

This is about this currently closed question: [I'm looking to play with the unique R/C cars only available in the demo versions — How can I do this?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101621/im-looking-to-play-with-the-unique-r-c-cars-ony-available-in-the-demo-versions)

From reading the question as originally posted by OP, it seems that the game, [Re-Volt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-Volt) has different demo versions, each with a different unique car only available to that demo version. He is looking for help where to get these demo versions. I assume that this is so that he (and other Re-Volt fans) can play those unique cars. I'm also a Re-Volt* fan, so I took the initiative to edit the question to try to get it reopened (as I also would like to try these unique cars).

The question, however has been closed as "*Not a real question - It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form*. "

After a few edits and at its current form, I feel that the question is now quite clear on what is being asked for. The OP even provided the details on the names, version and some of the unique cars of the different demo versions. I don't think it's a 'Shopping Advice' question, because of the same reasons.

Considering that, can we now get [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101621/im-looking-to-play-with-the-unique-r-c-cars-ony-available-in-the-demo-versions) reopened? If you don't agree with this (or if you're going to downvote), please kindly provide an answer or a comment below. Thank you.

<sup>*One of the best racing games ever</sup>

Comment: "I don't think it's a 'Shopping Advice' question, because of the same reasons."  How do any of the reasons you mention apply to shopping advice?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot The OP, in his question, specified and provided details of what he is looking for. "*The OP even provided the details on the names, version and some of the unique cars of the different demo versions.*"I reckon some of the close voters might have thought that it is similar to a "Shopping Advice" question, so I mentioned that.

Comment: Yeah, your rewrite of the question really salvaged it, IMO. I'd VtO it in its current state if I had 3k.

Comment: @galacticninja I'm not saying it _is_ a shopping rec.  I am saying those reasons don't make it not a shopping rec.

Comment: "*Those reasons don't make it not a shopping rec.*" [Can't really prove a negative, I'm afraid.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance)